# str_to_date in mysql for a string

Tags: mysql, date, str-to-date

I am getting the $date value as string. How to convert it into date format

I am getting `$date='2015-12-01'` i.e, $date in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. I want to convert it into date format using `str_to_date` like year-month-date

i.e `$date='2015-12-01'` must be converted to date format `$date=2015-12-01` in mysql query.

What is the date format that I have to give?

Comment: MySQL recognizes strings in that format as dates.  You can also just use `date($date)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `str_to_date`

```
str_to_date('2015-12-01','%Y-%m-%d')
```

other option

```
CAST('2015-12-01' AS DATETIME)
```

> but if your date format is `'%Y-%m-%d' or '2015-12-01'` MySQL auto
>   recognizes as dates